# Content form Nutch indexed on solr does not found on Drupal Search

Tags: solr, drupal-7, nutch

I have crawled the data from nutch(1.12) and indexed the content to apache solr(4.10.4) and i have indexed the drupal(7) content also to apache solr on same core.But while searching the indexed content in the site i am able to get only content that indexed from the drupal. The content indexed from the apache nutch is not found on searching. Here is sample content Indexed from the Drupal and Nutch.

Drupal Content Indexed to Solr:

```
{
        "id": "atrpeb/node/1",
        "site": "http://localhost/drupal-7.51/",
        "hash": "atrpeb",
        "entity_id": 1,
        "entity_type": "node",
        "bundle": "article",
        "bundle_name": "Article",
        "ss_language": "und",
        "path": "node/1",
        "url": "http://localhost/drupal-7.51/node/1",
        "label": "lorem",
        "spell": [
          "lorem",
          " dsgdsghjghjityjh dgsag ",
          "dgsag"
        ],
        "content": " dsgdsghjghjityjh dgsag ",
        "teaser": " dsgdsghjghjityjh dgsag ",
        "ss_name": "admin",
        "tos_name": "admin",
        "ss_name_formatted": "admin",
        "tos_name_formatted": "admin",
        "is_uid": 1,
        "bs_status": true,
        "bs_sticky": false,
        "bs_promote": true,
        "is_tnid": 0,
        "bs_translate": false,
        "ds_created": "2016-11-03T10:18:22Z",
        "ds_changed": "2016-11-03T10:18:22Z",
        "ds_last_comment_or_change": "2016-11-03T10:18:22Z",
        "im_field_tags": [
          1
        ],
        "tid": [
          1
        ],
        "im_vid_1": [
          1
        ],
        "sm_vid_Tags": [
          "dgsag"
        ],
        "tm_vid_1_names": [
          "dgsag"
        ],
        "_version_": 1551771958829383700,
        "timestamp": "2016-11-23T07:11:02.052Z"
},
```

Nutch Content indexed to Solr:

```
{
        "id": "http://www.apple.com/apple-pay/",
        "url": "http://www.apple.com/apple-pay/",
        "content": "Apple Pay - Apple Open Menu Close Menu Apple Shopping Bag Apple Mac iPad iPhone Watch TV Music Support Search
                apple.com Shopping Bag Make secure purchases in stores, in apps, and
                now on the web.",
        "spell": [
                "Apple Pay - Apple Open Menu Close Menu Apple Shopping Bag Apple Mac iPad iPhone Watch TV Music Support Search apple.com Shopping Bag Make secure purchases in stores, in apps, and now on the web."
        ],
        "_version_": 1551772050149867500,
        "timestamp": "2016-11-23T07:12:28.977Z"
},
```

Comment: Have you checked which filters Drupal applies to the search? (if it filters on fields that are not present in the Nutch content, you won't get any of that content for example) How are you actually searching the content? You can see the actual queries performed in the Solr log if the log level is high enough.